# Differential geometry, show a curve parameterizes a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

So I have this exercise from differential geometry and I am struggling with how to show that this is indeed a valid parameterization.

Let $n(\phi) = (\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))$. Show that the curve

$$c(\phi) = n'(\phi) - n(\phi)$$

parametrizes a circle.

What I have so far:

By this definition, $$c(\phi)= (-\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi),\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi))$$

so then $$c'(\phi)=(-\cos(\phi) + \sin(\phi),-\sin(\phi)-\cos(\phi))$$

which implies $$|c'(\phi)|=\sqrt[2]{(-\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi))^2 +(-1^2)(\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi))^2}=\sqrt[2]{\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi) -2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)+\cos^2(\phi)+2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)}=\sqrt[2]{2}\neq 0$$

So since $|c'(\phi)|\neq 0$, then it is smooth. But I don't think this is sufficient for showing that the provided curve parameterizes a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

$c(\phi) = (-\cos \phi - \sin \phi, \cos \phi - \sin \phi), \tag 1$

we have

$\vert c(\phi) \vert^2 = (\cos \phi + \sin \phi)^2 + (\cos \phi - \sin \phi)^2$
$= \cos^2 \phi + 2 \cos \phi \sin \phi + \sin^2 \phi + \cos^2 \phi - 2\cos \phi \sin \phi + \sin^2 \phi$
$= 2(\cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi) = 2, \tag 2$

whence

$\vert c(\phi) \vert = \sqrt 2, \tag 3$

which shows that the curve $c(\phi)$ is contained in the circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at the origin.  Our OP geoplanted has shown that also

$\vert c'(\phi) \vert = \sqrt 2 \tag 4$

(in fact it is essentially the same calculation as (2)); thus the curve $c(\phi)$ is *regular*, and of constant speed $\sqrt 2$; this in turn implies it completely traverses the circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at the origin whenever $\phi$ increases by

$\Delta \phi = \dfrac{2\pi \sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2} = 2\pi; \tag 5$

we thus see that not only does $c(\phi)$ lie *in* this circle, it in fact passes through each and every one of the circle's points, hence $\text{Range} (c(\phi))$ *is* said circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at $(0, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that thank's to the addition formula for $\sin$ and $\cos$ we have :

$$-\cos \theta - \sin \theta = -\sqrt{2} \sin \left ( \theta + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

$$\cos \theta - \sin \theta = \sqrt{2} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} - \theta \right)$$

Hence it parameterizes a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I follow the steps for the addition formulae, but how does this arrive at the conclusion that it is a circle of radius $\sqrt[2]{2}$ centered at the origin? Also does that mean that my computation above was not required?

Comment: @geoplanted since $(-\sqrt{2} \sin \left ( \theta + \frac{\pi}{4} \right))^2 + (\sqrt{2} \sin \left (- \theta + \frac{\pi}{4} \right))^2 = 2$., so this is the equation $x^2+y^2 = 2$ which is the equation of a circle centered at the origin of radius $\sqrt{2}$. Yes your computations are not required, since we are not asking about how smooth your curve is but about it's shape, so basically here you don't need to look at the derivative